# Projection matrix of $X$ multiplied by a column of $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define the projection matrix of $X \in M_{n \times k}(\mathbb{R})$ by $$P_X = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\text{.}$$
Suppose $X$ is partitioned by $X = [X_1 \mid X_2 \mid \cdots \mid X_k]$ (so each $X_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$).

I need to show that $P_XX_j = X_j$ for all $j$.

I don't see an easy way to do this without element-wise comparison. I have already proven that $P_X X = X$ and $P_X$ is both idempotent and symmetric.

Now $P_XX_j = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}X_j$.

I can't see another way of proceeding from here other than to do elementwise comparison of this resulting matrix. Is there a way to avoid having to look at every cell of the matrix?

Comment: You have $X_j = X e_j$, hence $P_X X_j = P_X X e_j = X e_j = X_j$.