# Let $\mathbf{u} \in \text{Span}(C(X))$, where $X \in M_{n \times k}(\mathbb{R})$. What is $P_{X}\mathbf{u}$, $P_{X}$ the projection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{u} \in \text{Span}(C(X))$, where $X \in M_{n \times k}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C$ denotes the column space.

How do I show that $P_{X}\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}$, where $P_{X}$ is defined by $$P_{X} = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\text{?}$$

Using an idea I received from [Projection matrix of $X$ multiplied by a column of $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575730/projection-matrix-of-x-multiplied-by-a-column-of-x), since $\mathbf{u}\in \text{Span}(C(X))$ (and assuming $X_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$)
$$\mathbf{u} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_iX_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}c_iXe_i$$
where $e_i$ is from the usual standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. But if I try to do $P_{X}\mathbf{u}$, this doesn't look like it's going to come out very cleanly, since I can't write $\mathbf{u}$ as a matrix (i.e., without the summation term).

Is there any way to avoid looking at each cell of $P_{X}\mathbf{u}$ and comparing it to each cell of $\mathbf{u}$ to prove equality?

Some possibly useful facts:

1. $P_X$ is idempotent.
2. $P_X$ is symmetric.
3. $P_XX = X$
4. If $X_i$ is a column of $X$, then $P_X X_i = X_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf{u} \in \text{Span}(C(X))$, then we can write it as a linear combinations of columns of $X$ and apply $P_X$ to each of the columns.

I.e. there exist integers $i_1, \dots, i_p$  and reals $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_p$ such that $\mathbf{u} =  \sum_{j=1}^p \alpha_j X_{i_j}$, where $X_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$.

Then your property 4 yields

$$P_X \mathbf{u} = P_X \sum_{j=1}^p \alpha_j X_{i_j} = \sum_{j=1}^p \alpha_j P_X X_{i_j} = \sum_{j=1}^p \alpha_j X_{i_j} = \mathbf{u},$$

using only linearity of $P_X,$ which comes from $P_X$ being a composition of matrices.